# Output JSON in Azure Function Logs

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub, serilog, ilogger

We'd like to send structured log data from our Azure Functions to Event Hub. So I set up Serilog to log to the console and include all the info I wanted. But now I come to try this in Azure, all of my nice Json formatted data from Serilog is being ignored - and only the standard ILogger output is being shown :(

Here's the config I'm using in `Startup.ConfigureServices`.

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(CreateLogger()));

private static Logger CreateLogger()
{
    var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithCorrelationIdHeader("X-Request-Id")
    .WriteTo.Console(new ElasticsearchJsonFormatter())
    .WriteTo.File(new ElasticsearchJsonFormatter(),
        $@"D:\home\LogFiles\Application\{applicationName}.txt",
        fileSizeLimitBytes: 1_000_000,
        rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
        shared: true,
        flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

}
```

Then I'm logging using ILogger in my function:

```
[FunctionName("Health")]
public IActionResult Health([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "users/health")] 
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a health request.");
    return new OkObjectResult("Users is healthy");
}
```

And locally I get both logs - the normal text `C# HTTP trigger function processed a health request.` but also a big JSON blob as expected. However, when running in Azure, when I look in Log Stream, I only see the normal text log :(

I can see the expected output in the file - but I want to be able to use Diagnostic settings to export the logs - and I can't select a log file there! :(

Comment: Can you provide a sample code? Then we can test it for you.

Comment: @TonyJu What else do I need to provide, sorry? It will require an Azure account to test... If you start with the example C# (precompiled) function code, then install Serilog and Serilog EaslticSearchJsonFormatter, then release to Azure and hit the endpoint, you should see the issue (it doesn't show the Json formatted output). I actually _haven't_ done that simple test. But I assume that's correct! 

I believe that the only way to get output into the trace log is by wrapping the ILogger instance you're given in the function invocation (or from the ILoggerFactory) with Serilog and Sink to it

Comment: A solution is needed for this when running in docker for all underlying runtimes needed to replicate an azure function. Ex. When running in AKS. Open logging in json format seems to be the new norm.